# Can author of question reject good edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, rejected-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8137651

I have changed a typo in question title, it was approved by 2 peers, but rejected by the question author with reason that there is no typo.

In text of the question it is correct, but in the title it is wrong.

Can author of question always reject all edits?

Comment: The tag should have been removed all together from the title

Comment: @rene I don't know, in cases where it wouldn't be in the top 2 tags to automatically be included, having it *in the title* for reasons of discoverability is acceptable I think, though obviously preferable if it is naturally incorporated such as "In X how Y" rather than "X - Y?"

Comment: I agree @TZHX but in this particular case the tag is noise.

Comment: @Marki555, I feel your pain ;)  (similar thing happened to my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12665116))

Comment: @Marki555, It's worth noting that you could resubmit your edit per this [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300300/one-of-my-suggested-edits-has-been-rejected-but-i-still-think-it-was-a-good-one?rq=1).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The original poster always has a binding vote on any suggested edits -- assuming they see it before the review queue has completed.

Comment: Do such rejects affect my edit suggestion history/reputation?

Comment: If by reputation, you mean statistics, yes. It will show as a rejected edit (which it is). If by reputation, you mean the +2 you would get if the edit were approved, you obviously don't get that when the edit is rejected.