# One of my suggested edits has been rejected, but I still think it was a good one. Should I re-submit it?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I have suggested [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8944318) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652534/print-on-the-screen-the-symbol-as-text) about how to display backslashes in C++. The problem is that the OP didn't format his code properly, it was normal text, and to have 2 backslashes appear, he typed 3. Then somebody edited the post for him and formatted the code. At this point, all 3 backslashes were displayed, which is not what the OP wanted. I tried to edit the post and restore the correct number (2); my comment was:

> The previous edit added code formatting, which disables the escaping of `\`. The OP had typed 3 of them, to have 2 displayed. Now, with the code formatting, they are all shown, so to restore the original question one backslash must be deleted. Please check previous versions/edits to see what I mean.

So **my intent was to restore the original post**. The first 2 reviewers understood it, but the last 3 didn't - and ironically their answer was

> "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

The result is that **now all the answers look wrong (even the accepted one!), whereas it's actually the *question* that is now wrong** (=different from the original one). So I still think the edit should be approved. This is not even the first time it has happened to me, so I am wondering what I should do now. I think flagging for moderator attention is overkill, and (almost) an abuse of the system. Should I just re-submit my edit and hope to get luckier? Or should I vote to rollback the edit that introduced the problem, and then submit one more myself? (I don't think I can do it on non-wiki posts, though)

### UPDATE

We have a happy ending! :-)
The OP has seen my comment and answered:

> Thanks for your point, Fabio, I just edited the post so that the \ is only seen twice as intended.

So, as far as this specific problem is concerned, everything is solved now.
And as a general rule for what must be done in these cases, I'd say the community is split between the "post it again" and "just let it go" positions (right now it's 4 vs 4). So I guess situations like this one have to be decided on a case-by-case basis.

### UPDATE 2

I think I was too hasty to accept an answer. I have to say I didn't expect so much interest in this question. Instead, votes kept coming. Now things have stabilized (despite a new answer), and as noted by Nathan Tuggy, there is now a clear majority (23 vs 12) in favor of his answer.

We can draw this conclusion: in this specific case it was not *completely* clear what the OP meant, so judging whether my edit was OK is a tough call. Let's forget about it and let's focus on the general case: if a **clearly** good edit is rejected, most people think it's fine to resubmit it **once**. Not more than that, to avoid triggering edit wars, but it can be done.

Comment: As I think, you edit the code part in question, so it is rejected based on "Conflict with author's intent"'.  and Reviewers generally reject when change the Code unless just the formatting

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName You are right, though reviewers failed to reject it the first time when, in my opinion, was the right thing to do (first edit was approved), and appear to have failed now understanding Fabio's comment and following his instructions, which would make clear why his edit was correct.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Yes**, you should resubmit it … ***once***. Make sure that there's a comment (there is), that there is nothing in your edit that is at all questionable except the single crucial edit (there isn't), that the edit summary is ridiculously clear about exactly what you're getting at (it was), and that you're absolutely correct in editing (seems like it?). Then resubmit to try to minimize the chance of getting a glitchy rejection. Again, *once*.

Suggested edit reviewers on SO are terrible, relatively speaking. That's why accepting and rejecting edits requires an extra vote compared to *any other site on the network* (yes, even SU and SF require only two votes to approve or reject). But if you keep getting rejections repeatedly, chances are still pretty good it's not the fault of the reviewers per se, but something wrong either in your edit or in how you justified the edit. Convince the reviewers!

<sub>*(This post is written chiefly from the perspective of a jaded suggested edit reviewer who would really like to see more genuinely good, non-trivial suggestions.)*</sub>

Comment: I've had code edits rejected where the original code was so wrong it was guaranteed to crash.  The best thing to do after following your advice is to post your own answer.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: A good point. If you've tried commenting on an answer and tried suggesting edits and you're not getting through, an answer of your own is the way to go. In this case that wouldn't help, since it's an edit to the question, but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede That's probably because you're really not supposed to make code edits. Fixing grammar, formatting, etc. are fine, but you should never be making an edit that changes the meaning of somebody's post, and that includes code.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: You should (just about) never edit code in someone's *question*, but believing you should avoid editing code in *answers* is a grave misconception. If the code can be improved in some verifiable way, it should be, for at least two main reasons that do not apply to questions: there is no issue with removing the real source of the problem by mistake, while correctness and code quality are far more important for answers than for questions. (I took Kevin's comment to be referring to editing answers, as it makes little sense otherwise.)

Answer (score 11):

No, you should not resubmit the edit for a few reasons. It is best to only submit the *same* edit on a post once - that was its one chance.

Resubmitting the edit begins to get into undesirable behavior. The worst case scenario is an "edit war" where two users will continuously revert back to their edit or their desired edit. Often a moderator will be flagged and manually handle these situations; it is unfortunate because moderators have such limited time, their time would best be spent on things which are less petty such as voting fraud or spam accounts.

Another possibility would be that the edit is rejected a second time. Continuously having edits rejected can lead to a temporary loss of that ability at some point.

In this exact case, I believe it was hard to determine what the OP's intention was with the excessive or not forward slashes. From my observation, they seem to be intentional (as in that was verbatim from their code) and they were just rendered out in the post. Given this perspective, I believe your edit was correctly rejected for changing the post (while not radical, it was still a departure from the original intent).

As you were just trying to help, and even came to meta to get some guidance, I would just keep on trying to help people with edits and be a little more wary in the future to just reproduce what was in the post verbatim if text is being converted into code. Code edits can be tricky.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right that rejected edits shouldn't be resubmitted, I hadn't thought about edit wars but the risk (in general, not in this case) is real. And in this particular case, since we are talking about a downvoted question that is a duplicate, I don't even think it makes sense to spend too much time and effort to improve it. I'll just let it go. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

As one of the reviewers who *approved*...

I remember this one, because it took a bit longer than the average review having to evaluate a few things.
Looking at the history now, I can see I made a mistake in approving.

---

### The problem

(I see this issue in hindsight..)

While the original question only *displayed* 2 slashes, the OP had actually *typed* 3 slashes which can be seen in [the source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65760536-8960-49be-8ff5-0cced6c90e09/view-source) (which I viewed at the time of reviewing).

Then the *first* edit wrapped the 3 backslashes in code formatting, which then actually *displayed* all 3 slashes.

Then Fabio made an edit suggestion to "fix" this.
Your (Fabio) edit comment was quite informative, but there was a mistake in there which I mistakenly agreed with:

> The previous edit added code formatting, which disables the escaping of '\'. *The OP had typed 3 of them, to have 2 displayed*

I can (now) see this was incorrect assumption, because we do not know what the OPs intentions where here.

Perhaps the OP:

1. Typed 3 slashes because their actual code has 3 slashes, and they
   were not aware the site had escaped one of them
2. Their code has 2 slashes, but OP was aware (or discovered) the site
   escaped 1 of 2 slashes so entered a 3rd slash to *display* 2 slashes
3. Perhaps they wanted 2 slashes displaying as per their question, but
   their code had 3 slashes, or vice-versa (which could have been their
   *issue*)

Or maybe... etc etc ... the point is we *did not know* what the OP wanted.

---

### What should have happened

The only true resolve to any of the edits and reviews would have been ask for clarification from the OP.

**The first edit:**
Upon attempting to add code formatting, the first editor should have realised they do not know if the OP intended to display 2 slashes using the 3rd slash for escaping, or if they actually had 3 slashes in their code.

The first editor should have commented asking for clarification from the OP, as *could* the reviewers of this first edit.

Whether the first edit should have been submitted and/or approved or not is another matter, but all along the line, the issue was no-one knew what the OP's intentions where.

**The suggested edit:**
Fabio's edit should have also *instead* been a comment requesting clarification from the OP.

**Review of suggested edit:**
My review of Fabio's suggested edit should have been a reject, and a comment in the question asking for clarification from the OP.

**The answers:**
The answerers to this question also needed clarification from the OP, as the answers depended upon how many slashes the OP wanted to display and how many were in their code.

3 of the 4 answers were posted before the *first* edit, but obviously it's unfair to expect answerers to identify that the slashes in the  post have no formatting and so there might be escaping going on.
Their expected knowledge is the basis of the question, not site markdown and how slashes are escaped in posts etc (although in an *ideal* world..).

So at some point one of the reviewers or suggested editors (including myself) should have commented and cleared up the issue for all concerned.

---

### OP's intentions

As it turns out, the OP has confirmed they only wanted 2 slashes showing, so obviously did know about escaping.

OP comment:

> Thanks for your point, Fabio, I just edited the post so that the \ is
>   only seen twice as intended.

But this only happened *after* the first edit and Fabio's suggested edit and the reviewers of it.

---

### To be fair to Fabio

I feel the need to highlight a few things here.

Fabio commented before submitting the suggested edit:

> Ironically, you have just faced this problem: in your original post
>   you had to type the `\` 3 times (it should actually be 4) in order to
>   have it displayed twice. That's because they are escaped. Now somebody
>   has edited your post by adding the code formatting, which disables the
>   escape, so we all see 3 backslashes instead of 2. C++ does the same
>   thing as this site.

It turns out this was correct, but it was a *presumption* as the OP *might have* had 3 slashes in their code and not known about the site escaping (no offence Fabio :)).

Rightly or wrongly, at least Fabio made the effort to comment, which also prompted the OP to fix their post, and provided a great example in relation to what the OP was asking about.
I wish I could see such good community spirit and positive outcomes more often..

And most certainly kudos for your *good intentions* here:

- Spending a fair bit of time trying to resolve a problem, commenting,
  and suggesting edits
- Following up here with this question
- And certainly a notable mention for the suggested edit comment.
  Although it was presumptuous, and I wrongly agreed, it was *informative* -
  better than the usual edit comment of "some formatting" but the post
  has all sorts of changes going on

---

### My bad

As it turns out, my approval was correct, as OP's intentions were to only display 2 slashes, but I did not know this when I reviewed so I should have rejected.

So I did make a mistake in judgement here, but to be a little fair on me *and* everyone concerned, this is a rare case specifically because of slashes escaping in the post output, and as a result not knowing what the OP's intentions were.

It also wasn't from a lack of care or want for quality for the site, as I spent a min or two reviewing this suggested edit alone.

I did make the mistake however, and certainly something learned from it :)

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed analysis. And don't worry about the offence, I've taken none, as it's obvious you don't want to offend anybody. I have just changed the accepted answer to Nathan Tuggy's, simply because it's the one that we could take as a future reference for similar cases - though I hope there won't be so many. I for one will pay more attention to how **really** sure I am that my edits are correct! ;-)

Comment: @FabioTurati Me too, we both learned something here, although as said it was a rare scenario :)