# What is the point of voting if "reject and edit" closes the vote in the "suggest edit" review?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, rejected-edits

I did a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14529961), I didn't know if it was a good answer, but I found that it could be. So I just [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14530020) to improve the post a little.

As you can see [Erik Godard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376371/erik-godard) approved but [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) came and rejected my edit. I did not know that my edit was wrong and it's okay that it has been refused. I don't care.

But I don't understand why "reject and edit" closes the vote. I don't see the point of voting if one user can decide alone. Plus, if 3 users say to me "you are wrong", I will try to understand why. But here one says "ok" and one other says "no". **There is a system to vote but you create a way to bypass it, why.**

- The system should wait for 3 voters who rehect or approve before processing the new edit. The system could propose the new edit to the next reviewer so he could see if this edit is better or not. He could improve it as well.
- This system doesn't make sense, maybe we should remove this vote?
  Because you create a backdoor, voting seems useless.
- We could open this queue to the >1k user. They will need to vote, but users with >2k don't and could use "reject and edit" or "approve and edit". That will make more sense. But we must not permit this if one review (vote) has already been done by a user with >1k. Because this again would not make sense. Of course It would be nice if a >2k user could choose to vote like a >1k user.

---

This happen again:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14708633, "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.", @Galik, do the same thing that me with his/her edit.

Comment: You pointlessly capitalize `It`- why do you expect this edit to be accepted? There are only two alternatives - accept and reject... Clearly should not be accepted, which leaves only one option - "reject" (or "reject and edit" which is the same for editor)... You also have not edited out comment from the answer ... and did not make answer acceptable quality (also adding explanation during edit is likely to be rejected too - posting own answer would be more appropriate)

Comment: You potentially mistook my comment for an answer... You provided link to an edit in the post and I got feel that you believe that your suggestion was good - so I *commented* on that part. If the only question you have "why 'reject and edit'  or 'approve and edit' considered binding vote" you don't need any information on history of your question, instead some reasoning why you think behavior is wrong would significantly improve this question.

Comment: Here is some info on dealing with "try this" so-called "answers" - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality - editing to improve such post to acceptable quality requires adding good explanation which puts words in original author mouth and likely will be correctly rejected as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of an email I sent to the SE team - their response was that abusing "reject and edit" and "improve edit" to singlehandedly approve/reject suggested edits is an occurrence rare enough that it's feasible to suspend abusers and revert the approvals/rejections manually.

Comment: Responding to the edit I rejected and did myself. The reason I rejected and re-edited was that the pending edit did not "respect the author's intention" in that it changed the original author's coding style. Rather than accept that I decided to keep the author's original coding style and simply fix the slight indentation problem. Editing should not be an excuse to impose your own preferred coding style over that of the question's author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will focus on one point you raised which, I believe, is the focal point of your question, and of your disagreement with S.L. Barth's answer:

> This system doesn't make sense, maybe we should remove this vote? Because you create a backdoor voting seem useless.

"Improve" and "Reject and Edit" can only be considered a backdoor on the voting system if you assume the main purpose of requiring multiple votes is making the judgement of edits fairer from the point of view of the editor by not leaving the decision to any single reviewer. That, however, is not the case. There is no requirement that more than one user reviews the edit -- a single reviewer who knows what they are doing is enough. Multiple votes are required to make it harder for users mindlessly clicking the "Approve" and "Reject" buttons to single-handedly approve or reject an edit (such users are often referred to as "robo-reviewers"). If a reviewer takes the trouble to make adjustments to the edit, it is far less likely that they are reviewing mindlessly, and so there is no need to wait for further votes before making the decision effective.

P.S.: While I am convinced that this interpretation matches the spirit of the relevant Stack Overflow rules, as well as the way in which they are enforced, I do not have a direct quote from Meta or the Help Center that literally supports it. Still, there are plenty of Meta discussions that indirectly lend support to my views about the point of edit review voting. Some of them are listed below:

- [*Require more than two coinciding votes to approve/reject a suggested edit*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142954/242059)
- [*Are the new suggested-edit beta stats leading to increased unilateral decisions?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141315/242059)
- [*One of my suggested edits has been rejected, but I still think it was a good one. Should I re-submit it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300300/2751851)
- [*Can we make rejecting suggested edits easier?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258397/2751851)

Comment: As the author of the other answer, I think this answers the raised point very well.

Answer (score 9):

The user chose "Reject and Edit", which replaces their edit with yours.

I don't know why he chose "Reject and Edit" and not "Improve", but I guess it's because your edit left a grammatical error and introduced another one.
You changed "If it still not working" to "If It still not working" - that second word should not start with a capital. User paxdiablo changed it into "If it is still not working" - adding the necessary verb, "is".

You should be more careful about editing grammar - this type of Reject *does* count towards an edit ban. The post you link to, refers to edits that are rejected due to a conflict of *concurrent* edits. In this case it wasn't a concurrent edit, but a rejection during review.

**Regarding your now edited question:**
A reviewer can create a new edit, that comes in place of yours. There is no longer a reason to vote on your edit if it is replaced by another.
Reviewers have this option because, having full edit privileges, there are trusted to know how to edit properly. And sometimes a post needs editing, but the suggested edit on it is simply bad. In that case a reviewer can choose to discard the current edit entirely, and use their editing privilege to create something (hopefully) better.

This does indeed mean that a user can single-handedly reject your edits, even when that user is not the OP of the post being edited.

But, there are consequences for the reviewer as well!

- If a reviewer chooses "Improve and Edit", they edit the post as it would be after your edit was applied.
- If a reviewer chooses "Reject and Edit", they edit the post as it was before you suggested the edit.

So, if your edit fixes a lot, and does not introduce errors - then it is easier for the reviewer to use "Improve Edit" than to use "Reject and Edit".
Conversely, if your edit introduces a lot of errors, it is easier for the reviewer to choose "Reject and Edit".

So, your best bet is to make the edit as good as you can. Make sure you fix as much as you can. Then hope the reviewer will prefer "Approve" or "Improve" to "Reject" or "Reject and Edit".

Comment: "I" must be capitalized, but not "it"... I hate this. Thanks, I didn't see that. But why he don't need to vote?

Comment: @Stargateur If by "vote" you mean Accept or Reject - a "Reject and Edit" overrules your edit suggestion.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes. The reviewer creates an entirely new edit, that replaces yours. This is how a user can single-handedly reject an edit, even when they're not the OP of the post being edited.

Comment: @Stargateur How should it work instead? The only alternative I can think of that is not completely unworkable would be making a "Reject and Edit" not count as a rejection (even though the edit *was* rejected!), which would make the review system quite a bit less effective. (Also note that if such a change actually happened, consistency would demand that "Improve" shouldn't count as an accept either.)

Comment: @Stargateur That would, in effect, send the alternative edit by the >2k user to the review queue. I don't think that is a workable solution.

Comment: There "consequences" are not, you just say what it happens. That is not a "consequence". Again, it's doesn't answer me, why create a voting system with a backdoor. Maybe I should rework my question again? I can't believe that is not a mistake.

Comment: @Stargateur No, it is not a mistake. The reviewer has this choice because they have full editing privileges. And it was badly needed, too, at least until edits were rate-limited recently. It used to be that you could flood the review queue with bad edits, and they would be robo-approved. Rejecting these with "Reject and Edit" was one of our few lines of defense.